# pages accordion tabs

Tags: jquery

I am given a website designing in wordpress(cms)..

[image]

This is accordion menu tab screenshot.

As shown  in the screenshot when you click  on **Category A (2)** the sub categories under it are listed..And clicking on the **Range 1** , pages under it are listed.

So now the actual thing that i need is..

Once you click on **Product A1** It should expand and display the content of page **Product A1**  and not in other window or tab,

I know this  can be achieved by Accordion tabs

But in case of accordion tabs i can only input the content there itself ...not in other page

```
           [accordion] content [/accordion]-->i want the content from page
```

do I have to use some jquery functions to achieve this? or is there aother plugin ?

Comment: You can load data dynamically using ajax.

Comment: thanks ..but is there plugin for the same ..or i l have to code for it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#accordion').accordion({
        create: function (event, ui) {
            $('div#accordion > div').each(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                $(this).load(id+'.html', function () {
                    $('#accordion').accordion('resize');
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```